# Voting up/down button in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning Rails, and am writing a simple app that will handle notes. Notes have a value "score" that is an integer. I want the user to press a button named "vote up" and one "vote down", and voting up will make score=score+1.

The notes_controller.rb has a method 'upvote' that looks like

```
def upvote
  @note = Note.find params[:id]

  @note.score = @note.score +1
end
```

But I can not figure out how to route so that sending a POST (or UPDATE?) to /notes/:id/upvote makes the note's `score` change?

Comment: have you tried /notes/upvote/:id?  that should call the upvote method of the notes controller passing the :id as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your routes file:

```
resources :notes do
  member do
    put :upvote
  end
end
```

This will create the named route `upvote_note_path` which will point `/notes/:id/upvote`, and will run your NotesController upvote action.